# What is the best way to organize the code of a nodejs-express project, using TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

While trying to organize the code of my first NodeJS-express project, I ran into some doubts about the use of namespaces, modules and classes. When to choose one? When another?

For example, my project is structured (simplifying) in.

> routers -> controllers -> services -> repositories.

The possibilities I thought of to manage these "entities" are the following:

- Classes
- Classes with static methods
- Singletons
- Simple module export
- Namespaces

**Classes**

I thought of avoiding them right away, since the above-mentioned entities do not need to memorize any state. Furthermore, they would complicate the code due to the need to be instantiated.

**Classes with static methods**

They are correct? Or rather a simple namespace or simple export of the modules?

**Class + Singletons**

A way of organizing the code in a "nicer" way than the simple class, but which does not convince me, since reading on the net that the singleton in TypeScript is replaceable with the namespace.

**Simple module export**

The way I thought to implement immediately, for example in this way (file user.repository.ts):

```js
    const add = async (user: User): Promise<void> => {
        if(await canBeAdded(user)) {
            //save user;
        } else {
            // throw error
        }
    }

    export const UserRepository = {
        add
    }
```

It's corrects? Or am I not properly using what TypeScript offers? Being the first time I use this language, I would like to be sure I chose the right path.

**Namespaces**

Are they a better choice to develop the code published above? Are you advised against?

Thank you in advance for the answers! Any advice is welcome!

P.S. I know that, once the TypeScript is compiled, in Javascript the classes are practically syntactic sugar. What I'm interested in knowing are the best practices for writing good code in TypeScript.

Comment: Simple module exports of course. KISS. And yes, this is an opinion.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks for your reply!
Since Microsoft has yet to publish any TypeScript guidelines, the only way is to share opinions!

Comment: Yes, and they likely won't publish TypeScript guidelines except those that are used for their own development (e.g. on language itself). My advice is to write TypeScript how you would write JavaScript. The types don't alter the semantics.